# Why was this edit approved?

Tags: support, editing

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4152

Am I missing something? An anonymous user edited a pseudo answer into the **question** and it was approved? By two users?

Not to mention they removed a key word from the question. ("research")

I must be missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Dang, sorry about that Sam, I saw your name there, and thought you had suggested the edit on someone else's question.  I always get it backwards which is the edit and which is the original, and thought your edit made the question better....  Let me see if I can roll it back.

Comment: I wasn't involved in the question at all. I didn't edit it, I didn't comment on it, and I didn't answer it. Plus, I have enough rep now to edit questions without approval.

Comment: I think Larian is missing some coffee...  :)  Dude, wake up!  yeah, I know about that horrible layover you suffered through and your jet lag, but serisouly, you're losing it mate!

Comment: You're right Jason, I am still totally jet lagged from my trip.  That layover in Newark is brutal....